# Including Jquery in a Angular service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I am using a service that uses jquery, and $ still is not correctly injected

Service:

```
class Service{
constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $: JQueryStatic, private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
}
```

How can I include $ typing that is in my jquery.d.ts file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to use it as a service you could do:

```
yourAppModule.service('$',function(){return $;});
```

Which takes jquery from window and makes it an angular service. But it's just simpler to use jQuery off of window.

PS: Its better if you put any DOM access in an angular directive. Controllers really aren't the place for manual DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling in $ in the constructor when with jquery $ you simply need to reference the file.

Fixed code:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

class FileUploadService{
constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
}
```

I can now use $. to access jquery methods.